# Coordinate Systems Transformation(Rectangular to Cylindrical)

Tags: vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

I am new to this subject:

- Cartesian, Cylindrical and Spherical coordinate system.
- Coordinate System Transformation

I have this example problem that I cant get the right answer.

Transform to cylindrical coordinates:

(a) $F=10ax -8ay +6az$ at point $P(10, -8, 6)$.

One of my problem is

- I dont know when to use the dot product or matrix transformation
  equation. *Should I just solve for the cylindrical variables $(\rho,\phi,z)$ or use the dot product/matrix form to transform to another coordinate system?*

I tried solving it using the equations but I cant get the correct answer. The correct answer is $12.81a\rho + 6az$

Comment: The given answer makes no sense. Evaluating a function at a given point gives a **value**. Plugging $P=(10,-8,6)$ into $F$ gives $72a$.

Comment: What is $a$? Is it some arbitrary number?  Or are you trying to write a subscript?

Answer (score 1):

On which Approach to use:

- Dot product/Matrix multiplication approach: Use the matrix transformation approach when
  you want to express the entire vector in the new coordinate system using a
  transformation matrix.

If given a rectangular coordinate Q(x, y, z), to transform to cylindrical Q$(\rho, \phi, z)$, that is when you just solve for the cylindrical variables.

- $\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$
- $\phi = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$
- $z = z$

To express $\mathbf{F} = 10\mathbf{a}_x - 8\mathbf{a}_y + 6\mathbf{a}_z$ in cylindrical coordinates at the point $P(10, -8, 6)$

- $\hat{\rho} = \cos(\phi)\mathbf{a}_x + \sin(\phi)\mathbf{a}_y$
- $\hat{\phi} = -\sin(\phi)\mathbf{a}_x + \cos(\phi)\mathbf{a}_y$
- $\hat{z} = \mathbf{a}_z$

Solving for $\phi$:

- $\phi = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ = $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-8}{10}\right)$ = -38.65$^\circ$

Computing the Dot Products:

- $\mathbf{F}_\rho = \mathbf{F} \cdot \hat{\rho}$ =  $(10\mathbf{a}_x - 8\mathbf{a}_y + 6\mathbf{a}_z) \cdot (\cos(-38.65^\circ)\mathbf{a}_x + \sin(-38.65^\circ)\mathbf{a}_y + 0)$
- $\mathbf{F}_\phi = \mathbf{F} \cdot \hat{\phi}$ = $(10\mathbf{a}_x - 8\mathbf{a}_y + 6\mathbf{a}_z) \cdot (-\sin(-38.65^\circ)\mathbf{a}_x + \cos(-38.65^\circ)\mathbf{a}_y + 0)$
- $\mathbf{F}_z = \mathbf{F} \cdot \hat{z}$ = $(10\mathbf{a}_x - 8\mathbf{a}_y + 6\mathbf{a}_z) \cdot (0 + 0 +\mathbf{a}_z) $

Therefore;

- $\mathbf{F}_\rho$ = 12.80
- $\mathbf{F}_\phi$ = 2.19$\times 10^{-3} \approx 0$
- $\mathbf{F}_z$ = 6

$\therefore \mathbf{F}_\rho + \mathbf{F}_\phi + \mathbf{F}_z = 12.8\mathbf{a}_\rho + 6\mathbf{a}_z$

This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5I2HQikOXW4&t=730s Also, explains has the solution to the question.